# SSLHandshakeException: ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

i try to request a local service with https without certificate check. But i got this execption.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

here is a part of code:

```
try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
                    (hostname, session) -> hostname.equals("IPADDRESS"));
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.toString());
        }
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: The Server is using self-signed or expired certificate

Comment: self-signed certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy,

i resolved it with this code part:

```
private void disableCertificateVerification() {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)                  throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                    throws CertificateException {
            }
        } };

        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
                    (hostname, session) -> hostname.equals("IPADDRESS"));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

and i called this function before i created the RestTemplate.

Comment: Disabling TrustManager makes your client accept any certificate. This is discouraged . You should include trusted certificates in the truststore

Comment: i know, it just a test

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to incomplete trust path for the server certificate: the server certificate is probably not trusted by the client.

Usually the fix is to import the server certificate into the client trust store. The default trustStore is in jre/lib/security/cacerts but is is a better practice to use your own keystore

You can create an `SSLSocketFactory` and add to your connection before connecting or apply to all connections using the static method

```
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
```

This is an example to create the socket factory

```
/* Load the keyStore that includes the server cert as a "trusted" entry. */
KeyStore keyStore = ... 
TrustManagerFactory tmf = 
  TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
sslFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
```

Example of loading the keyStore

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(trustStore, trustStorePassword);
trustStore.close();
```

The trust store can also be configured using system properties

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "pathtoyourjavakeystorefile");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
```

The simplest way to create the key store file is using the GUI tool Portecle. *New KeyStore > Import Trusted certificates*

You can import the root certificate of the chain if you want to 'trust' all certificates from root, or import only the server certificate. For a self-signed certificate, import it directly

Comment: I disagree. Modifying the installed JRE is never a good idea - therefore this not the usual fix! Create a Java KeyStore file, create a TrustManager and initialize it using that KeyStore that is the usual and correct fix...

Comment: And you don't have to import the entire certificate chain. Just the head of it will do.

Comment: @Robert, you're right. The recommended way should be using your truststore instead of overwriting cacerts. I update the answer

Comment: @EJP, you can import the root certificate or the server certificate depending if you want to 'trust' all CA certificates or only the certificate of your server. Also I am going to include your comment in the answer

Comment: @EJP+pedrofb: A *self-signed* cert *is* a root so there is no difference in that case. For a 'real' chain -- one with multiple certs -- Java can use as trust anchor any cert you choose along that chain. There is also the option to use the default SSL factory with sysprops `javax.net.ssl.trustStore{,Password,Type}` as needed. See JSSE Reference Guide in the javadoc.